# Performance issue warning when debounce function is used

Tags: reactjs

I have a code like this:

```
function App() {
  const handleInputChange = React.useCallback(
    debounce(event => {
      event.persist();
      console.log(event.target.value);
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input name="search" type="search" onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When i typing in console I have this warning message:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
>   you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a
>   released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must
>   keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See
>   /react-event-pooling for more information.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-waterfall-x604c) codesandbox with example of code. What a i'm doing wrong?